# Linux on Lifebook P1610 Touch

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touch

i want to install Linux on my P1610.
I downloaded elementary OS and created a live USB stick.

Everything is working out of the box except the touch screen.

As elementray OS is related to ubuntu i tried to use this [guide](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Touchscreen/). 
But

```
sudo apt-get install xinput-calibrator
```

is not working.

On the fujitsu siemens support page there are only the drivers for WIN XP or vista.

Hmm... what can i try next?
Or does anybody know activate the tochscreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`sudo apt-get install xinput_calibrator`

I have Elementary OS and if I run xinput-calibrator from commandline, I need to type xinput_calibrator.